# How to put ubuntu 14.04 LTS into Performance mode

Tags: 14.04, performance, mode

I've tried the indicator-cpufreq but look at this: [Screenshot of the indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIDxb.jpg)

Rendimiento means High Performance and Ahorro de energía means Powersave.

Seems like the indicator is obsolete, is there any other indicator for 2016?

Comment: You can check if it is in performance or powersave mode: `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Install cpufrequtils:

```
sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils
```

Then edit the following file (if it doesn't exist, create it):

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/cpufrequtils
```

And add the following line to it:

> GOVERNOR="performance"

Save and exit.

Disable ondemand daemon

```
sudo update-rc.d ondemand disable
```

You can check your settings with:

```
cpufreq-info
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i still have these two options but now the indicator is animated and seems to work properly. Check this out: http://fotos.subefotos.com/ed2ee33dcbd0cbb10b3861dbdc75c111o.jpg